# backstage custom action executeShellCommand 'ENOENT',

Tags: typescript, backstage

I'm running backstage on** windows** to play with on my local desktop for now.

I followed the backstage documentation on custom actions: [custom actions](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-templates/writing-custom-actions/)

I did this successfully and was able to create a file. Now I wanted to try and execute a command in the background. I saw in the docs that there was a function for it. [executeShellCommand](https://backstage.io/docs/reference/plugin-scaffolder-backend.executeshellcommand)

I have following action defined:

```
    import { createTemplateAction } from '@backstage/plugin-scaffolder-node';
    import { executeShellCommand, RunCommandOptions } from '@backstage/plugin-scaffolder-backend';
    import { z } from 'zod';
    export const jenkinsCreateJob = () => {
      return createTemplateAction({
        id: 'myjenkins:create:job',
        schema: {
          input: z.object({
            jobname: z.string().describe('the name of the job to create'),
          }),
        },
        async handler(ctx) {
            const myoptions:RunCommandOptions =  {
                command: `echo ${ctx.input.jobname}`,
                args: []
            }
          await executeShellCommand(myoptions);
        },
      });
    };
```

when I run the action in a catalog I get:

```
2023-04-05T12:37:12.000Z Beginning step create jenkins job22023-04-05T12:37:12.000Z Error: spawn echo mytestapp3 ENOENT3    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)4    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)5    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Am I using this function wrong or?

I'm trying to execute a shell command to generate some stuff before creating a git repo.